# glDrawArrays specify different offsets

Tags: opengl, opencl

Consider the following situation:

Let `A,B` be VBO such that `size(A)=N*size(B)`. N `glDrawArrays` calls would be performed. The Vertex shader can compute one of the following inputs.

```
in VA: a1 a2 a3 a4 a5 ...
in VB: b1 b2 b3 b4 b5 ...

in VA: a1 a2 a3 a4 a5  ...
in VB: b6 b7 b8 b9 b10 ...

 ...
```

In this example one would have the following VBO's

```
A  = (a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,...)
B1 = (b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,...)
B2 = (b6,b7,b8,b9,b10,...)

  ...

BN = ( ... , B_(size(A)*N-1)), B_(size(A)*N))
```

with VAO's

```
V1 = (VA->A,VB->B1)
V2 = (VA->A,VB->B2)
  ...
VN = (VA->A,VB->BN)
```

`VA->A` means that vertex attribute `VA` points to VBO `A`.

The situation is that I computed the data within OpenCL using interoperability. From point of view from OpenCL calculations it is quiet elegant to use a kernel which writes the output into a **single buffer**, which is also my VBO.

So B looks like this:

```
B = (b1, b2, b3, ..., B_(size(A)*N))
```

Now I know for each chunk of the data that the corresponding x-axis looks like:

```
A = (a1, a2, a3, ... x_size(A))
```

To plot the data, my first attempt is to create a VBO `X` which is basically

```
X = (A, A, ...) = (a1, a2, a3, ... x_size(A), a1, a2, a3, ...)
```

and then use `position, length` arguments of `glDrawArrays` to render each  graph from it.

It would be a nice feature for me if I had any possibility to use only `A,B` as described instead of splitting `B` into several VBO or duplicate `X` into one big VBO `A`. So is this possible? If not: what could be a good strategy?

Comment: I'm confused about the memory layout here.  A VBO is one *contiguous* segment of memory, just like you get from `malloc()`.  If A is a VBO, how can it be in two places?  Do you mean that A and B are different vertex attributes?  Can you draw the memory layout you want in a straight line, instead of this 2D layout which is a bit ambiguous?

Comment: Or in other words, I'm not sure if this means `a1 a2 ... aN b1 b2 ... bN a1 a2 ... aN bN+1 bN+2 ... b2N`, or if it means `a1 b1 a2 b2 ... aN bN ...`

Comment: Sorry my first question was not precise, i updated the question. hopefully the situation gets more clear now

Comment: @keksnicoh: "*It would be a nice feature for me if I had any possibility to use only A,B as described instead of splitting B into several VBO or duplicate X into one big VBO A.*" Who says that you can't do this?

Comment: @Nicol Bolas: nobody, but I don't know how.

Comment: Just as a note. If you are creating that in OpenCL. You can always recur to using structs, if that helps you keep everything tidy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With OpenGL >=4.3 or ARB_vertex_attrib_binding you can use `glBindVertexBuffer()` to quickly rebind the B attribute to a different buffer or a different location in the same buffer.  You will still end up with multiple draw calls, and state changes between those draw calls, but this is a fairly cheap state change (as far as state changes go, it is one of the cheapest):

```
// Note: assuming A and B are just regular float, not vec2 or anything
// Omitted: VAO binding, enabling attributes, uniforms...

// Attribute locations
const int ATTRIB_A = 0, ATTRIB_B = 1;
// VBOs for A and B
GLuint buf_a, buf_b;
// Size of A = n, size of B = n * m
int n, m;

// Set the format for A and B
// Note: You can bind multiple attributes to each binding point,
// so hypothetical attribute C could share with A or B.
glVertexAttribFormat(ATTRIB_A, 1, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0);
glVertexAttribFormat(ATTRIB_A, 1, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0);

// Set the VBO binding points for A and B
glVertexAttribBinding(ATTRIB_A, 0);
glVertexAttribBinding(ATTRIB_B, 1);

// Bind your buffer for A
glBindVertexBuffer(0, buf_a, 0, sizeof(float));
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
    // Bind part of the buffer for B
    glBindVertexBuffer(1, buf_b, i * n * sizeof(float), sizeof(float));
    // Draw...
    glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, n);
}
```

With older versions of OpenGL, and without ARB_vertex_attrib_binding, you can call `glVertexAttribPointer()` in the loop instead of `glBindVertexBuffer()`.

Comment: glBindVertexBuffer is my thing here! To bad hat I stuck to core profile 4.1 on my mac.  Does glVertexAttribPointer helps me here? I cannot define an offset with this command.

Comment: Ah yes, I share your pain.  The offset is actually the last parameter to `glVertexAttribPointer`.  It only *looks* like a pointer, but it's actually an offset.

Comment: Yeah I read that just this moment here: https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_buffer_offset_and_stride . Thanks for the hints on this, looks like I can solve my problem like I hoped - even in OpenGL4.1CoreProfile.